# group data frame lines based on lagged difference

Tags: r

I'm struggling on a R programming problem.
I'm working on a data frame such as:

```
   START  STOP 
1    535   545 
2    545   555 
3    555   565 
4    565   575 
5    575   585 
6    585   595 
7    595   605 
8    605   615 
9    615   625 
10   625   635 
11  2635  2645 
12  2645  2655
```

I would like to group lines that are following one another over time (ie. lines 1 and 3 because 545 - 545 = 0, or small, >= - 20 for instance).

I calculate this like :

```
x <- df$STOP[1:(nrow(df)-1)] - df$START[2:nrow(df)]
```

Eventually with this piece of code for small gaps:

```
x <- ifelse(x >= -20, 0, x)
```

Now I would like to construct a columns GROUP based on comparison of the START value of line i+1 and the end value of line i.

If lines i and i+1 are considered as followers, I put them into a same group. Here, GROUP would be equal to '1' for lines 1 to 10 and to '2' for lines 11 and 12.

Then I would like to extract the very first start and last stop for each group (ie. group 1 start = 535 / end = 635 ; group 2 start = 2635 / end = 2655).

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cumsum(x < -20)` for the grouping variable. Below is by implementation using `dplyr`. I also used the `lag` function to calculate `x` (which I called `diff`).

```
require(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(diff = lag(STOP, default=-Inf) - START, 
              grp = cumsum(diff < -20))
```

You can then also easily get grouped summaries:

```
df %>% mutate(diff = lag(STOP, default=-Inf) - START, 
              grp = cumsum(diff < -20)) %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>%
  summarize(min(START), max(STOP)) %>%
  as.data.frame
```

Comment: wow ! impressive ! never used 'mutate', but it seems to be very powerful. Additional question: how to put the results into a regular data frame ? (grp|min(start)|max(stop)) ? Thx a lot !

Comment: ok ! I found the solution, juste need to add df <- before your code ! Thank you si much !!!